# Killing a restify server

Tags: node.js, restify

my server.js look like below:

```
var restify = require('restify')
var server = restify.createServer({
 log : log,
  name: demo
});

server.listen(8080,function(){
  console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

I start this server as

```
> node server.js
```

My question is.. what is the right way to stop the server.. simply kill the process or am I suppose to do something else ?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Yes, just kill the process. `Ctrl-C` in your terminal or killing the process id.

Also, if you want to do it programmatically, you can use `process.exit()` in your code, like a special route to shutdown.